# Jquery Repeater parse values in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, repeater

I've created a repeater in html/js. With the help of this [library](https://github.com/DubFriend/jquery.repeater). We want to parse the data when a user clicks on a button. (not there yet.)

But how do we read the data out of the elements like ingredienten[0][wat]
Because there can be many ingredienten[n][wat]

This is our code for a beter view of the problem:

```
<div id="tes0t" data-repeater-list="ingredienten">
    <div class="ingredientenlijst" data-repeater-item="">
      <input type="text" name="ingredienten[0][hoeveel]" placeholder="Hoeveel">
      <input type="text" name="ingredienten[0][wat]" placeholder="Van wat">


      <input data-repeater-delete="" type="button" value="Delete">
    </div>

  <div class="ingredientenlijst" data-repeater-item="" style="">
      <input type="text" name="ingredienten[1][hoeveel]" placeholder="Hoeveel">
      <input type="text" name="ingredienten[1][wat]" placeholder="Van wat">


      <input data-repeater-delete="" type="button" value="Delete">
    </div><div class="ingredientenlijst" data-repeater-item="" style="">
      <input type="text" name="ingredienten[2][hoeveel]" placeholder="Hoeveel">
      <input type="text" name="ingredienten[2][wat]" placeholder="Van wat">


      <input data-repeater-delete="" type="button" value="Delete">
    </div><div class="ingredientenlijst" data-repeater-item="" style="">
      <input type="text" name="ingredienten[3][hoeveel]" placeholder="Hoeveel">
      <input type="text" name="ingredienten[3][wat]" placeholder="Van wat">


      <input data-repeater-delete="" type="button" value="Delete">
    </div></div>
```

We tried to read it with jquery. But I think we're missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your using jQuery you can use its 'Attribute Contains Selector'-feature (https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
jQuery('input[name*="wat"]').each(function(e)
{
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

This will loop over all input elements that have 'wat' in their name and output the values in the console.

Alternatively, if you add some classes to the input fields (`class="hoeveel"` and `class="wat"`), you can loop over `.ingredientenlijst` and output their value like so:

```
jQuery('.ingredientenlijst').each(function(e)
{
    console.log($(this).find('.hoeveel').val() + ' van ' + $(this).find('.wat').val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As in this [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/k3a73vns/1/) to grab inputs with `hoeveel` placeholders

```
var itemsHoeveel = $('input').filter("[placeholder='Hoeveel']");
```

for inputs with `Van wat`

```
var itemsWat = $('input').filter("[placeholder='Van wat']");
```

```js
var itemsHoeveel = $('input').filter("[placeholder='Hoeveel']");
var itemsWat = $('input').filter("[placeholder='Van wat']");
itemsHoeveel.each(function() {
  $('#result').append($(this).attr('name') + '<br>');
});

$('#result').append('<hr>');
itemsWat.each(function() {
  $('#result').append($(this).attr('name') + '<br>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tes0t" data-repeater-list="ingredienten">
  <div class="ingredientenlijst" data-repeater-item="">
    <input type="text" name="ingredienten[0][hoeveel]" placeholder="Hoeveel">
    <input type="text" name="ingredienten[0][wat]" placeholder="Van wat">
    <input data-repeater-delete="" type="button" value="Delete">
  </div>
  <div class="ingredientenlijst" data-repeater-item="" style="">
    <input type="text" name="ingredienten[1][hoeveel]" placeholder="Hoeveel">
    <input type="text" name="ingredienten[1][wat]" placeholder="Van wat">
    <input data-repeater-delete="" type="button" value="Delete">
  </div>
  <div class="ingredientenlijst" data-repeater-item="" style="">
    <input type="text" name="ingredienten[2][hoeveel]" placeholder="Hoeveel">
    <input type="text" name="ingredienten[2][wat]" placeholder="Van wat">
    <input data-repeater-delete="" type="button" value="Delete">
  </div>
  <div class="ingredientenlijst" data-repeater-item="" style="">
    <input type="text" name="ingredienten[3][hoeveel]" placeholder="Hoeveel">
    <input type="text" name="ingredienten[3][wat]" placeholder="Van wat">
    <input data-repeater-delete="" type="button" value="Delete">
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="result"></div>
```